# Error while updating property 'items' of a view managed by: AndroidDialogPicker

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying make a Picker in react-native, but I getting a error: Error while updating property 'items' of a view managed by: AndroidDialogPicker

null

value for label cannot be cast from ReadableNativeMap to String

How I resolve this?

```
    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
        this.state = {
          categories: [
            {
            "description": "Meditações com foco na Respiração", 
            "id": 1, 
            "name": "Respiração"
          }, 
          {
            "description": "Meditações que projetam atenção nos sentidos e percepções do corpo, do ambiente.", 
            "id": 2, 
            "name": "Sensitiva"
          }, 
          {
            "description": "Meditação ativa, pode ser feita em durante outras atividades", 
            "id": 3, 
            "name": "Ativa"
          }]
        };
      }
     
    render() {
      
       return(

  <Picker 
                mode="dialog" 
                iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
                placeholder="Select your SIM"
                selectedValue={this.state.categorySelected}
                onValueChange={this.onValueChange.bind(this)}>
                
                  {this.state.categories.map((item, index) => {
                  return (<Picker.Item label={item} value={index} key={index}/>)   })}
                </Picker> 
)}
```

Comment: try <Picker.Item label={item.name} value={index} key={index}/>

Comment: Yes, worked! 
Thank you @GuruparanGiritharan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to using an object for the label which fails when it tries to map to label in native code.
You will have to set the item.name as label like below.

```
<Picker.Item label={item.name} value={index} key={index}/>
```